BalUn topology: How to reverse which ports are balanced and which are unbalanced?
I presume a BalUn's topology, determines which port pair is balanced port, and which are unbalanced ports, or does it? Because in the picture below, wire taps look entirely symmetrical.
And if topology does matter, in reference to the drawing below, could the unbalanced side be made the "step-up" side, by swapping the turns count on the transformer core, i.e., the where it calls for 4 turns, use 6, and vice-versa?


Just to start off with: this isn't a fantastic balun. The right side is "floating-ish" in that both terminals have a substantial impedance to ground, but the upper right terminal is a lot "further away" from ground than the lower right one, so the right side isn't, strictly speaking, balanced. It's a transformer, but its common-mode impedance will be disappointing. It might be saved by putting a good choke (1:1 balun) right at its input, provided that the "chassis ground" symbol in the schematic isn't actually connected to anything but the coax shield.
With that out of the way, on to the question you actually asked: you're right that the balun design is symmetrical. What makes it asymmetrical is that one side has a ground reference while the other side is floating (ish). Simply move that "ground" symbol and the "coax" symbol from the left side to the right side, and now the left side is balanced and the right side is unbalanced. The left side will still be low-impedance because it spans fewer turns of the transformer, and the right side will still be high-impedance because it spans more.

could the unbalanced side be made the "step-up" side, by swapping the turns count on the transformer core, i.e., the where it calls for 4 turns, use 6, and vice-versa?

No, that simply changes the ratio. Instead of a ((4+6)/4)^2 = 6.25:1 ratio, you'd end up with a ((6+4)/6)^2 = 2.78:1 ratio — i.e. roughly a 50 ohm to 150 ohm transformer. But the left side would still be the low-impedance one, and the right side still high-impedance, for the reasons mentioned before.

Thanks hobbs; After I thought about, I realized this is a BalBal, except for the fact that in the schematic show, it's being used in an Unbalanced application, which I presume it can, due to the symmetry of the windings, unlike a transformer where one of the ports was common, like on an UnUn.  Also, I understand your point about ground, but my application was simply unbalanced, not actually grounded. After posting this question, I realized that swapping the turns ratio did exactly what you describe...Funny how walking the dog in the woods, while thinking about a problem, can do that!

@LouisSeaman yeah, it's fine for "balbal" operation. But if you ground one terminal, the opposite side ends up neither balanced nor grounded :)


Because in the picture below, wire taps look entirely symmetrical. And if topology does matter, in reference to the drawing below, could the unbalanced side be made the "step-up" side, by swapping the turns count on the transformer core, i.e., the where it calls for 4 turns, use 6, and vice-versa?

The unbalanced left side will always be the lower impedance port.
Originally you have 8 turns (4+4) primary and 20 turns (6+4+4+6) secondary, which gives a turns ratio of 1 : 2.5 or an impedance ratio of 1 : 6.25 (50 : 312.5 Ohm).
After replacing the 4 turns with 6 turns and vice versa, the new turns ratio will be 1 : 1.67 (12 : 20 turns) or an equivalent impedance ratio of 1 : 2.777 (50 : 139 Ohm).

After posting this question, I realized that swapping the turns ratio did exactly what you describe...Funny how walking the dog in the woods, while thinking about a problem, can do that! Thanks for your response!
